# Elasticsearch aggregation on nested objects

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have an document with the following mappings:

```
{
  "some_doc_name": {
    "mappings": {
      "_doc": {
        "properties": {
          "stages": {
            "properties": {
              "name": {
               "type": "text"
              },
              "durationMillis": {
                "type": "long"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And I would like to have an aggregation like: "The average duration of the stages which name contains the SCM token"

I tried something like:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "scm_stage": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [{
            "match_phrase": {
              "stages.name": "SCM"
            }
          }]
        }  
      },
      "aggs" : {
        "avg_duration": { 
          "avg": { 
            "field": "stages.durationMillis"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But that's giving me the average of all stages for all documents that contain at least one stage with the SCM token. Any advice on how to get this aggregation right?

Comment: Is `stages` of `nested` type in your mapping?

Comment: No (a few more characters go comply with StackOverflow limits)

Comment: Then you need to in order to achieve what you want :-)

Comment: Just checking the docs and giving it a try right now. It's a bit strange that you have to opt-in for a behaviour like that, it's hard for me to image a case when I actually want all the array data flatten, I think indexing each object individually makes more sense as a default behaviour. Thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: It comes with a price, that's why it is not by default. It is a good thing that it is not opt-in as it makes you think why you want that behavior in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question thanks to the help of [val](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4604579/val)

My mappings file was missing the `"type": "nested",` something like:

```
...
"stages": {
  "type": "nested",
  "properties": {
    "id": {
    "type": "keyword",
    "ignore_above": 256
  },
  ...
```

Then I can get my aggregation working with something like this:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "stages",
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "stages.name": "scm"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "stages": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "stages"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "stages-filter": {
          "filter": {
            "terms": {
              "stages.name": [
                "scm"
              ]
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "avg_duration": {
              "avg": {
                "field": "stages.durationMillis"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```